# Uninstall neo4j in windows

Tags: windows, neo4j

I am trying to reinstall the Neo4j 1.0.19 on Windows. But, when I reinstall it, it is installing with previous instance. It is because of process related to Neo4j is running and also killed the process, cleaned everything. Can anyone help me with this in uninstalling Neo4j properly?

Comment: You can just delete the install folder. You might want to deregister the service first if you don't plan on reinstalling: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/windows/

Comment: I deregistered the service, cleared all files in appdata related to Neo4j and tempfiles. But, no use

Comment: I also have a doubt that, will it get conflicts if MSSQL is installed already in my system and after that I install Neo4j?